# Downloaded apps does not start, failed with error -10810

Tags: macbook-pro, error, mac-pro

I try to install SQLDeveloper.app that I downloaded from Oracle, but every time it gives me that error

> LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Users/peyo/Downloads/SQLDeveloper.app.

I have Java version 8 for Eclipse.

How can i fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error ...` is often an execute permissions error.

You can text the permissions of the overall app from terminal
`ls -l path/to/app`
but if that looks OK, you may need to test the executable within the app
`ls -l path/to/app/Contents/MacOS/app`

Simple example using Calculator…

```
$ ls -l /Applications/Calculator.app/Contents/MacOS/Calculator
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  143648  3 Dec 06:43  
/Applications/Calculator.app/Contents/MacOS/Calculator
```

If you don't see the `x` execute permission, you can add it with
`chmod +x path/to/app/Contents/MacOS/app`

There's an alternative approach which *may* work.
On first run, rather than double-clicking, right-click & select Open from the drop menu. This will bypass Gatekeeper's quarantine & allow it to run. It should then remember this for subsequent launches.

Comment: when i use this command ls-l here is the result
$ ls -l Downloads/SQLDeveloper.app
total 0
drwxr-xr-x@ 7 peyo  staff  238 Dec 18 02:55 Contents

Comment: So you need to test `$ ls -l Downloads/SQLDeveloper.app/Contents/MacOS/SQLDeveloper`